# What is the name, if it exists, for a concurrency structure that allows parallel processing but writes in the order received?

Tags: rust, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a Rust-based latency-sensitive application that subscribes to a stream of incoming data, deserializes it, processes the deserialized object, and then forwards it elsewhere.

Sometimes, I receive bursts of messages and this causes the latency to degrade a bit as it is "backed up." It would be great if I could parallelize the deserialization.

However, I need to preserve the order of the messages when I forward them along. Forwarding is extremely fast, almost negligible, so the fact that forwarding is serial is okay.

Naively, I could send a tuple of `(sequence_number, data)` over a channel to a pool of processor threads, and each thread could, upon processing, send a tuple of `(sequence_number, processed)` over a different channel to a single thread that simply forwards. The forwarding thread would also keep track of the next `sequence_number` to send. When it receives something over the channel, it saves to a `HashMap<u64, MyData>`. Then while the map contains the next `sequence_number`, it could forward.

But it gives me pause that I couldn't find such a library on GitHub; makes me think this could be a bad idea.

So I am wondering, is there a name for this sort of thing? Does it exist in Rust or some other language? Is there a better pattern I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of a common term but you could use [`FuturesOrdered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesOrdered.html) from the `futures` crate.

Here is an example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=55afcbf288a63c858f527e96e6711382)):

```rust
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use futures::stream::FuturesOrdered;
use futures::StreamExt as _;
use std::thread;
use core::time::Duration;


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut ord_futures = FuturesOrdered::new();
    for i in 0..100 {
        // receive
        ord_futures.push(async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(thread_rng().gen_range(1..5))).await;
            println!("processed {i}");
            i
        });
    }

    while let Some(i) = ord_futures.next().await {
        // forward
        println!("received {i}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this schedule all the work in one thread, though? I assume that `ord_futures.push(async move { ... })` will schedule it in the event loop, which is single threaded, but I'm trying to get parallelism...